# Calculus the extreme value of the function $f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Calculus the extreme value of the $f(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}+xy+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}$

pleasee help me.

Comment: What have you done so far? Why don't you try the usual derivative tests?

Comment: Over what region? (This is highly relevant information.)

Comment: Note that a local maximum or minimum need not be a global one. Set $y=1, x=\pm \frac 1n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the normal derivative test. First order conditions
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x+y-\frac 1{x^2}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y+x-\frac 1{y^2}=0$$
If $x,y\in \mathbb R$ the the solution is $x=y=\frac 1{3^{1/3}}$

Answer (score 0):

min{$f(x, y) = x^2+y^2+x y+1/x+1/y$}~~4.32675 at (x, y)~~(0.693361, 0.693361)

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2Cy%29%3Dx%5E%7B2%7D%2By%5E%7B2%7D%2Bxy%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7By%7D

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with the am/gm inequality, by rewriting the function $ x^2 + y^2 + xy + 1/(3x) + 1/(3x) + 1/(3x) + 1/(3y) + 1/(3y) + 1/(3y)$. This will have an absolute minimum for positive x,y when all the terms are equal.

Comment: And what leads you to believe we should assume that $x,y$ are positive>